# insert formulas in the last row of a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that fetches data (formulas) from a worktab and copies it to the second row of the calling worktab.
This row two is inserted before, this works. Maybe a bit slow but that is a different topic.
But now I want to insert a row as the last row and copy the formulas there. I have managed to insert the last row.
I have no idea how to do the rest. Attached below the script
So I would like to insert instead of in cell L2, in cell L Lastrow the formula from the sheet Formulas A2.

```
function NewT() {
  // activate the T sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var TSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('T');
  TSheet.activate();  
    
// Insert last row
   var numberrows = TSheet.getMaxRows()
   TSheet.insertRowsAfter(numberrows,1)

  // Now fill in the formulas for the Trade
  var formulas = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Formulas');
  
  // declare a two-dimensional area of (TSheet, formulas) cell references
  // then just iterate through the array copying from formulas to Tsheet
  var myMap = [ ['L2', 'A2'],
               ['M2', 'A3'], 
               ['N2', 'A4'], 
               ['O2', 'A5'], 
               ['P2', 'A6'], 
               ['Q2', 'A7'], 
               ['R2', 'A8'], 
               ['S2', 'A9'], 
               ['T2', 'A10'], 
               ['U2', 'A11'], 
               ['V2', 'A12'], 
               ['W2', 'A13'], 
               ['X2', 'A14'], 
               ['Y2', 'A15']];
              // ['AE2', 'A21']];
               
    var i;
    var l = myMap.length;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    TSheet.getRange(myMap[i][0]).setValue(formulas.getRange(myMap[i][1]).getValue());
    
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work?  First of all getValues()/setValues() will not copy formulas, only values. You need to use getFormulas()/setFormulas().  Second if there are any relative cell references, your copying from a column to a row, not sure how the cell references will  hold up.

Comment: Also getFormulas()/setFormulas() basically copys as text so there is no adjustement of cell references for displacement.  You need to use Range.copyTo() to get adjusted references.

Comment: @TheWizEd thank you for your comment. The script take from the worktab "Formulas" from cell A2 to cell A15 formulas in textform to the cells L2-Y2 in the calling sheet. this works. And the formulas work then fine. As i wrote, i want to change the script. Add a row as a last row. and the copy the information from A2-A15 to L Lastrow- Y Lastrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
function NewT() {
  // activate the T sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var TSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('T');
  TSheet.activate();  
    
// Insert last row
   var numberrows = TSheet.getMaxRows()
   TSheet.insertRowsAfter(numberrows,1)

  // Now fill in the formulas for the Trade
  var formulas = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Formulas');
  
  // declare a two-dimensional area of (TSheet, formulas) cell references
  // then just iterate through the array copying from formulas to Tsheet
  var myMap = [ ['L2', 'A2'],
               ['M2', 'A3'], 
               ['N2', 'A4'], 
               ['O2', 'A5'], 
               ['P2', 'A6'], 
               ['Q2', 'A7'], 
               ['R2', 'A8'], 
               ['S2', 'A9'], 
               ['T2', 'A10'], 
               ['U2', 'A11'], 
               ['V2', 'A12'], 
               ['W2', 'A13'], 
               ['X2', 'A14'], 
               ['Y2', 'A15']];
              // ['AE2', 'A21']];
               
    var i;
    var l = myMap.length;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    TSheet.getRange(myMap[i][0]).setFormula(formulas.getRange(myMap[i][1]).getFormula());
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

I have included only the portion to copy formulas (as text) to the last row.  It is how I would do it for any row.  Rather then do each row in a loop I would get the values/formulas I want with one instruction in this case `var formulas = TSheet.getRange(2,1,14,1).getFormulas(); // Get A2:A15`.  This gives a 2D array of [[A2],[A3],[A4],...].  i Then I convert to a 1D array using `Array.forEach()`, [A2,A3,A4,...].  Now I can put the formulas any where I want with `setFormulas()`.  I put the transpose array within array brackets [transpose] to create a 2D array for `setFormulas()`.

This assumes that there are no relative formula references that do not copy properly.

**Script**

```
function NewT() {
  // activate the T sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var TSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('T');
    
  // Now fill in the formulas for the Trade
  var formulas = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Formulas');

  formulas = formulas.getRange(2,1,14,1).getFormulas(); // Get A2:A15
  var transpose = [];
  formulas.forEach( row => transpose.push(row[0]) ); // transpose [[1],[2],[3]] to [1,2,3]
  // L is column 12
  Tsheet.getRange(Tsheet.getLastRow()+1,12,1,transpose.lenth).setFormulas([transpose]);  // L(last row +1):Y(last row +1)
}
```

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String)
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp